# Which fields of Computer Science are involved in knowledge-based and text-based dialog systems?

Tags: natural-language-processing, knowledge-representation

One of my future goals is to know in depth about building a text-based dialog system to answer questions about a specific topic (say, Tolkien's legendarium), assume that I have a large body of article-formed facts about that topic (say, Wikipedia). Excluding the "Computer Engineering" part of the problem, I have a question:

Which (narrow enough) fields of Computer Science are involved in the problem, and how deep is the involvement of each of them? With my knowledge right now, I can only pinpoint the field of Natural Language Processing (NLP), but I don't know how deep it's involved in the problem and whether we can narrow it more. Also, I just feel that Information Retrieval (IR) and Knowledge-based System (KBS) are involved, but actually I don't know them too well. That's all I have for now.

**Addition:** I'll use the example of the Tolkien's legendarium to make sample **facts** and a sample **question**. Sample *facts*: "Melkor (known in Sindarin as Morgoth), the evil Vala, corrupted many Maiar into his service. These included Sauron, the main antagonist of The Lord of the Rings, and the Balrogs, his demons of flame and shadow" (from the Wikipedia page of Maia). The sample *question*: "List all named Maiar who were tempted and served under Morgoth."

Comment: This seems to be too broad to me; we don't know enough about the problem to give narrow enough answers, so guesswork will ensure. Community votes, please!

Comment: Could you specify what does "fact" and "question" looks like for you? NLP is for sure good one, KBS - hard to tell your objective. Could you give some minimal example of query to that system? By second question do you mean the techniques used are sufficient to solve your problem?

Comment: @Evil I'll use the example of the Tolkien's legendarium. So, sample facts: "Melkor (known in Sindarin as Morgoth), the evil Vala, corrupted many Maiar into his service. These included Sauron, the main antagonist of The Lord of the Rings, and the Balrogs, his demons of flame and shadow." (from the Wikipedia page of Maia), and a sample question: "List all named Maiar who were tempted and served under Morgoth." About KBS, I just feel that it may be involved, I'm totally not sure. Actually, I don't know KBS that well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I strongly suggest to incorporate your comments into question (via edit). Also I have read the Tolkien's books, but not everyone (with 100% probability) does, so it is crucial to let everyone understand - hence examples. The second part I can hint tou right now - yes, you have to research and also provide dictionary - e.g. Maiar not Maias, list of subjects etc. Also NLP does not work flawless, so... We also discourage multiple questions per post, but the second part - you can strip that question, you need to research further.

Comment: It would also be (my not humble opinion) better to ask how to achieve your goal and elaborate on it rather than asking about narrow fields - you will still need several of them and they are not 100% working yet (otherwise we would querry the questions to search engines like in your example). It is awesome that you want to research the topics to prepare, but it will yield vast list of fields and be based on opinion (there are plenty ways to do it, dependent on task and the person who answers it, so specified task is really needed).

Comment: @Evil I really appreciate your answers. Every bit is very helpful. There's just one thing I want to make (more) clearer that is I'm OK with doing the "dirty" work of preparing data, making dictionaries, making rules, etc. I'm just afraid that the problem is not good enough for research, academically. In addition, I'm a kind of guy that really desires overview. I think I can work out the specific things to do to achieve the goal, later.
P.S: I'll definitely edit my post.

Comment: I think there should be one more edit (to clarify further the task you have and avoid asking about list of fields, which may come as the answer anyway). I do not know about the academic part - you should consult your advisor / teacher. It also depends on the project - if your project will handle / improve some NLP issues - this is probably good one, if this will be just working project from working algorithms (unless project requirement is like this) it may be too small one - but still this is not good question to any third-party - always consult your advisor.